# Where is file that i could edit Assembly version

Tags: c#, version, .net-assembly

I have an application in c# and I want set the version of my application 
by `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version`, but my problem is
how I could edit the value of it and where is the file that the value of version is written on it?

Answer (score 0):

Its in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, under your Properties folder:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("ConsoleTests")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("ConsoleTests")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2015")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("e2e2a417-bd3d-414d-97f9-91196ce1c63a")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

The last two lines identify the file version and the assembly version, those are what you edit to change the version. Depending on what IDE you use, the file may or may not look the same as above, but what you are looking for are the **AssemblyVersion** and **AssemblyFileVersion** assembly attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio, you can also change the version by right-clicking on the project, choosing Properties, Application tab, and then click the "Assembly Information" tab. You will then see something like the following dialog, where you can edit the Assembly and File versions:

[image]